# Set of LUTs which guarantee unique integer combination

Tags: c, permutation, discrete-mathematics

Say I have 8 tables of 16 values:

```
uint32_t lut[8][16];
```

I want to fill these tables with values such that combining (add, eor, whatever) one entry from each of the eight tables will produce a unique 32-bit value -- being distinct from the result of combining any other set of entries.

That is to say, for random variables `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, and `p`, I want unique results from `lut[0][i] + lut[1][j] + lut[2][k] + lut[3][l] + lut[4][m] + lut[5][n] + lut[6][o] + lut[7][p]` for all the different values that those variables can have.  Although the combining operation need not necessarily be plus.

In total there are `16**8` (four billion) combinations of input, and the results of each of those must be distinct.

Additionally -- and this is the hard part -- I want these entries to appear random.

The obvious answer is:

```
uint32_t lut[8][16] = {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
    { 0x00, 0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60 /* ... */ },
    { 0x000, 0x100, 0x2000 /* ... */ },
    /* ... */
};
```

And we can prove that it works with:

```
for (uint64_t x = 0; x < 0x100000000; x++) {
  uint32_t y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    y += lut[i][(x >> (i * 4)) & 15];
  }
  assert(x == y);
}
```

But that's not random at all!

I can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  shuffle(lut[i], 16);
}
```

That helps a little, but not much.

What I've ended up doing is a bunch of transforms on the above example.  Any 1:1 *linear* transform that I can perform on the combined value to make it 'more random', can be performed on the table elements ahead of time, and if I get the same result as if I'd done it after then I've proved that every possible combination still produces a unique value (because it did before the transform).

There are a few limitations to that approach, though.  So I wonder; is there another way to randomise these tables with the given constraints?

Comment: Why don't you do the  "reversed operation" instead? Choose 8 random 32-bit values, and then "split" each one of them into the table at the corresponding index.

Comment: @barakmanos There are 4 billion (16 to the power of 8) possible combinations of tables, so when I distribute a 32-bit result through the tables I have to consider how its pieces interact with different choices from different table entries; and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done.

Any 1:1 hash-like transform that I could do to the combined result I can also do to the tables beforehand, so long as those transforms are linear.

So, if I can do this:

```
uint32_t y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  y += lut[i][(x >> (i * 4)) & 15];
}
y = transform(y);
```

Then, so long as `transform()` is linear, I can do this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    lut[i][j] = transform([i][j]);
  }
}
```

And I can be very aggressive in that function because I need only do it once to set up the tables.

As an initial operation I can reorder the bits, because none of the bits overlap meaning there's no carry behaviour to worry about:

```
uint32_t bitpermute(uint32_t x) {
  int s = 1;
  uint32_t y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if ((x & 1) != 0) {
      y |= 1 << (a & 31);
    }
    a = a * 1103515245 + 12345;
    x >>= 1;
  }
  return y;
}

uint32_t transform(uint32_t x) {
  return bitpermute(x);
}
```

And I can multiply by an odd number (any odd number is co-prime with the implicit modulo of `uint32_t`, so it always has a 1:1 mapping):

```
uint32_t transform(uint32_t x) {
  return bitpermute(x) * 0x39597a05;
}
```

The problem here is that low-order bits can't be affected by high-order bits, so a change to the input that causes a high bit to change (high after the `bitpermute()`) won't have any effect on the lower bits.  We can't right-shift, because that's not linear.  Right-shift before the combining operation has different carry propagation from right-shift after it.

Those carries are ruining everything!

To get the carry bit out of the equation, we can change domains.  Make our plus a plus-mod2 (exclusive-or):

```
uint32_t y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    y ^= lut[i][(x >> (i * 4)) & 15];
}
```

Now our multiplication has to be replaced with something comparable:

```
uint32_t bitmix(uint32_t x, uint32_t p, int s) {
  uint32_t y = 0;
  while (p > 0) {
    if ((p & 1) != 0) {
      y ^= x;
    }
    x = (s > 0) ? (x >> -s) : (x << s);
    p >>= 1;
  }
  return y;
}

uint32_t transform(uint32_t x) {
  x = bitpermute(x);
  x = bitmixup(x, 0x39597a05, 1);
  x = bitmixdn(x, 0x1b0bb8ad, -1);
  x = bitmixup(x, 0x09bb8825, 1);
  return x;
}
```

There, I fixed it.

Sadly this sacrifices a benefit of carries, that the combination of adjacent bits can affect other bits... but I can do mixing from any bit to any other bit if they all follow the same pattern.

Rather than mod-2 arithmetic (using `^` in place of `+`), I could make it mod-4 using this idiom: `r = x + y - (x & y & 0xaaaaaaaa)` and then I have to constrain all my shifts to being even.  I haven't investigated this, though, as I'm not sure it's going in a direction that's helpful.